# Constructing high resolution images in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, large-data

Say I have some huge amount of data stored in an HDF5 data file (size: 20k x 20k, if not more) and I want to create an image from all of this data using Python. Obviously, this much data cannot be opened and stored in the memory without an error. Therefore, is there some other library or method that would not require all of the data to be dumped into the memory and then processed into an image (like how the libraries: Image, matplotlib, numpy, etc. handle it)?

Thanks.

This question comes from a similar question I asked: [Generating pcolormesh images from very large data sets saved in H5 files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921997/generating-pcolormesh-images-from-very-large-data-sets-saved-in-h5-files-with-py) But I think that the question I posed here covers a broader range of applications.

---

**EDIT (7.6.2013)**

Allow me to clarify my question further: In the first question (the link), I was using the easiest method I could think of to generate an image from a large collection of data stored in multiple files. This method was to import the data, generate a pcolormesh plot using matplotlib, and then save a high resolution image from this plot. But there are obvious memory limitations to this approach. I can only import about 10 data sets from the files before I reach a memory error.

In that question, I was asking if there is a better method to patch together the data sets (that are saved in HDF5 files) into a single image without importing all of the data into the memory of the computer. (I will likely require 100s of these data sets to be patched together into a single image.) Also, I need to do everything in Python to make it automated (as this script will need to be run very often for different data sets).

The real question I discovered while trying to get this to work using various libraries is: How can I work with high resolution images in Python? For example, if I have a very high resolution PNG image, how can I manipulate it with Python (crop, split, run through an fft, etc.)? In my experience, I have always run into memory issues when trying to import high resolution images (think ridiculously high resolution pictures from a microscope or telescope (my application is a microscope)). Are there any libraries designed to handle such images?

Or, conversely, how can I generate a high resolution image from a massive amount of data saved in a file with Python? Again the data file could be arbitrarily large (5-6 Gigabytes if not larger).

But in my actual application, my question is: Is there a library or some kind of technique that would allow me to take all of the data sets that I receive from my device (which are saved in HDF5) and patch them together to generate an image from all of them? Or I could save all of the data sets in a single (very large) HDF5 file. Then how could I import this one file and then create an image from its data?

I do not care about displaying the data in some interactive plot. The resolution of the plot is not important. I can easily use a lower resolution for it, but I must be able to generate and save a high resolution image from the data.

Hope this clarifies my question. Feel free to ask any other questions about my question.

Comment: It can be done with GDAL, see for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911590/can-you-loop-through-pixels-in-an-image-without-loading-the-whole-image/14912580#14912580

Comment: Can you use the hdf image api?

Comment: This question is not very clear. You don't seem to want an image, but a visualisation of your data in the form of `pcolormesh` or `imshow`. (Note that 20k x 20k in `Float32` is only 1.5 Gb, are you sure you don't have this?) Also, the approach in your other question can lead to a different intensity scaling in each sub-image. If you know the bounds of your image, I'd suggest creating an empty uint8 array (less memory usage) for the whole thing, and then populate it by scaling each sub-image to the min/max of the data. If that fails, I'd save each image as png and merge them with ImageMagick.

Comment: @tiago Please see edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You say it "obviously can't be stored in memory", but the following calculations say otherwise.

```
20,000 * 20,000 pixels * 4 channels = 1.6GB
```

Most reasonably modern computers have 8GB to 16GB of memory so handling 1.6GB shouldn't be a problem.

However, in order to handle the patchworking you need to do, you could stream each pixel from one file into the other. This assumes the format is a lossless bitmap using a linear encoding format like BMP or TIFF. Simply read each file and append to your result file.

You may need to get a bit clever if the files are different sizes or patched together in some type of grid. In that case, you'd need to calculate the total dimensions of the resulting image and offset the file writing pointer.